# How to open-close a Sidebar with jQuery with advanced settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, sidebar, animated

I created a open-close animation but it doesn't exactly do what i want.

I can't figure out how to fix the following:

1. Sidebar shall open and close only when i click the magnifier icon, not when i click into the blue area of the sidebar (like when i want to type something into the search box or click any content that is displayed there.
2. Apparantly when the side is loaded i need to click twice on the magnifier icon to open the sidebar. Really don't know why :/

See link to JS Fiddle below:

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code for my own blog. Demo [here](http://www.mwanoz.fr/).

As you can see, the 1st time you click on the icon, it open the sidebar. Just click on the icon again to close it. Here's the jQuery code (can be improved):

```
$('#icox').on('click', function() {
    $(this).children().toggleClass('active');
    $('#menux').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Then in CSS you just have to play with `margin-left: -300px;` or with css3 `transform: translate`.

Both methods should works fine but I think the CSS way is better (in my opinion) :)

Here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6H8xr/

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your sidebar has the "open" class when it loads.

html:

```
<div id="peek" class="open">
```

and your js:

```
$('#icox').on('click', function(){
  var $this = $("#peek");
```

I updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d69ne/4/

Comment: OHH Thanks!! forgot about that. Any ideas how to prevent the sidebar from closing when i click in the search form??

Comment: Bam! (Edited my answer ^)

Answer (score 0):

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/d69ne/2/

1. solved here

You need click event on image and not your huge sidebar.

```
$('#peek_img').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $('#peek');
    if ($this.hasClass('open')) {
        $this.animate({
            left: '0px'
        }, 500).removeClass('open');
    } else {
        $this.animate({
            left: -200
        }, 500).addClass('open');
    }
});
```

2 solved here

```
<div id="peek" class="open">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('#icox').on('click', function(){
  if ($('#peek').hasClass('open')) {
    $('#peek').animate({
      left : '0px'
    }, 500).removeClass('open');
  } else {
    $('#peek').animate({
      left : -200
    }, 500).addClass('open');
  }
});
```

with:

```
<div id="peek" class="open">
```

edit: with a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d69ne/3/)